# Wordpress Checkbox never updates on profile page

Tags: php, wordpress

Totally stumped.  I have a checkbox on the user profile page but it refuses to update.  Its not even an array set value or anything, just never sets...Seems like no data gets passed to the post value...

updated as per @RST and now as per @simon-pollard

```
   // This will show below the color scheme and above username field
add_action( 'profile_personal_options', 'extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'update_field_value' ); 
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'update_field_value' );

function extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    // get the value of a single meta key
    $user_id =  $user->ID;
    echo "user id: " . $user_id . "<br/>";
    $meta_value = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'emailPrefs', true ); // $user contains WP_User object
    // do something with it.
  echo "checked value: " . $meta_value. "<br/>";
    ?> 
    <h2>Email Settings</h2>
    <table class="form-table">
    <th scope="row" id="lbl-subtitle" for="email-settings">Email on Timer Reset</th>
    <td><fieldset>
<form method='post' action="profile.php">

    <input type="checkbox" id="email-settings" name='email-settings'
<?php if ($meta_value == '1'){ echo 'checked'; } ?> value ="<?php echo $meta_value?>" />

    </form>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </td>
    </fieldset>
    </table>
    <?php


}

function update_field_value($user) {

 $user_id =$user->ID;

    if (isset($_POST['email-settings']) && $_POST['email-settings'] == 'on') { 
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'emailPrefs', '1'); 
    } else { 
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'emailPrefs', NULL); 
    }


}
```

Comment: Put the update command in a seperate function and use the  add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'your_update_function' );
 add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'your_update_function' );

Comment: Try changing 'if (!empty($_POST['email-settings']))'  to ... `if (isset($_POST['email-settings']) && $_POST['email-settings'] == 'on')` I think at the moment you are always setting it to '' and btw you should set it to null :) not ''

Comment: @SimonPollard I tried isset initially and read that it would _always_ evaluate to true with a checkbox value. Nothing updates so its like my function isn't getting called

Comment: Echo out some stuff in your function and use a break; this will cause the page to literally break but will help. So firstly echo $user_id and $_POST['email-settings'] and see what you get for them. This will also let you know if you function is running. Hope that makes sense

Comment: so `wp_die()` right?...yeah that does it....okay so nothing is set on post...now what????...okay I see the checkbox is set but not the user..hmm...I think this calls for a hidden field with that value set???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Simon.  With his help, I saw that the `$user` object was not accessible on that update hook meaning the user_meta never updated.  To work around this I've created a hidden form field to store my userID so that it's available as a post variable.

Here is the Final Code:

```
// This will show below the color scheme and above username field
add_action( 'profile_personal_options', 'extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'update_field_value' ); 
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'update_field_value' );

function extra_profile_fields( $user ) {
    // get the value of a single meta key
    $user_id =  $user->ID;
    echo "user id: " . $user_id . "<br/>";
    $meta_value = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'emailPrefs', true ); // $user contains WP_User object
    // do something with it.
  echo "checked value: " . $meta_value. "<br/>";
    ?> 
    <h2>Email Settings</h2>
    <table class="form-table">
    <th scope="row" id="lbl-subtitle" for="email-settings">Email on Timer Reset</th>
    <td><fieldset>
<form method='post' action="profile.php">
 <input type='hidden' name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id ?>" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="email-settings" name='email-settings'
<?php if ($meta_value == '1'){ echo 'checked'; } ?> />

    </form>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
    </td>
    </fieldset>
    </table>
    <?php


}

function update_field_value($user_id) {

$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
// echo $user_id;

// echo $_POST['email-settings'];

// wp_die();

    if ( isset($_POST['email-settings'], $_POST['user_id'] ) && $_POST['email-settings'] == 'on') { 
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'emailPrefs', '1'); 
    } else { 
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'emailPrefs', NULL); 
    }


}
```

Leaving in the commented out portion so future readers can check this for themselves.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you - I would wrap an isset around the user_id bit as well for better validation etc... I can edit your answer if you want to show you what I mean

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I"ll go on and do that as well :)